# Changing a boolean stored in JSON with Angular?

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I am trying to change a boolean value when a user clicks on a table row that is populated with JSON. For example I have this...

```
$scope.prices = {
"Prices": [
    {
        "Code": "edl",
        "Selected": false
    },
    {
        "Code": "ead",
        "Selected": false
    }
]
}
```

Which I then bind to a table...

```
<table>
<tr ng-click="change(item.code)" ng-repeat="item in prices">
    <td>{{prices.Code}}</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

And when a user clicks on a row the change function is fired that would then change the selected value to either true or false

```
$scope.change = function (itemCode) {
//update the clicked code selcted value to True/False
// first check if its true or false
// then change it accordingly
// Please excuse my terrible attempt!
if(!$scope.prices.code.selected){
    $scope.prices.code.selected = true
} else {
    $scope.prices.code.selected = false
}
};
```

As I'm not sure how to achieve this from the change function. Or is there another way? Thanks

Comment: data doesn't match html and `ng-repeat` isn't used properly either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, it doesn't make much sense to have an extra level in `$scope.prices` before you get to the actual array of prices.

In other words, instead of having:

```
$scope.prices = {
"Prices": [
    {
        "Code": "edl",
        "Selected": false
    },
    // etc.
]
};
```

You should just have the array straight up, so you can bind to it easily:

```
$scope.prices = [
    {
        "Code": "edl",
        "Selected": false
    },
    // etc
];
```

Then you can bind to it like so:

```
<table>
    <tr ng-click="change(item)" ng-repeat="item in prices">
        <td>{{item.Code}}</td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Finally, now that `$scope.change()` gets the whole item, instead of just the code, you can toggle its `Selected` property directly:

```
$scope.change = function (item) {
    item.Selected = !item.Selected;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

First a few corrections.

1. Refer to the array `Prices` inside `$scope.prices`.
2. Change the signature of the `change()` so that it gets the reference to the item that was clicked.

   ```
   <table>
     <tr ng-click="change(item)" ng-repeat="item in prices.Prices">
       <td>{{item.Code}}</td>
    </tr>
   </table>
   ```

   Now implement the change method

   ```
   $scope.change = function (item) {
     if (item.Selected) {
       item.Selected = false;
     } else {
       item.Selected = true;
     }
   };
   ```

Comment: This would work. The `$scope.change()` function could be more succinct, but your version is definitely clear.

Comment: @GrelL the one line implementation is perfect if that's the intent of the `change` method. If so, I think it should be renamed to `toggleSelection`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another cleaner solution without involving functions, this approach will release you from removing functions from $scope if you are cautious of memory usage.

```
<table>
    <tr ng-click="item.Selected = !item.Selected" ng-repeat="item in prices">
        <td>{{item.Code}}</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Happy Helping!